# Survival probability of a random walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

I was looking for the probability that a discrete random walk stays below a certain level for $n$ steps. $x_0$ denotes the initial position and the position at the $i$-th step is $x_i=x_{i-1} + \eta_i$ where $\eta_i$ is a continouous and symmetric jump. I am interested in:
$$q_n(x|y)=Pr[x_1 \leq y, \dots, x_{n-1} \leq y, y \leq x_n \leq x]$$
I know that for $y=0$ this is related to the well known Sparre-Andersen result. Are there any analytical results on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is $\eta_i$ distributed?

Comment: A gaussian with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$, $\eta_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$